# 配列の中身がnilになってしまう

Tags: swift, ios

このようにして、配列を組みました。しかし、runするとimage1～image6がnilと出てしまいます。（プロジェクト内にsampleという画像はあります）
原因を教えてくださると幸いです。

```
    let image1 = UIImage(named: "sample")
    let image2 = UIImage(named: "sample")
    let image3 = UIImage(named: "sample")
    let image4 = UIImage(named: "sample")
    let image5 = UIImage(named: "sample")
    let image6 = UIImage(named: "sample")

    let img = [image1!,image2!,image3!,image4!,image5!,image6!]
```

Comment: sampleという画像は xcassets で管理されていますか？

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage(named: "sample.png")` のように拡張子を指定するとどうでしょうか？

また、画像ファイルの「Target Membership」にチェックは入っていますか？

[image: Target Membership]